# JAXB and Hibernate - programmatically controlling output

Tags: hibernate, jaxb, moxy

I've got a number of Hibernate-backed classes that are fronted with a RESTful interface.  I would like limit the output of proxied objects by default, while also supporting full population of objects on a client-specified basis.

Say I have a set of classes like this:

```
public interface ID
{
    public int getID();
    public void setID(int id);
}

@XmlRootElement
public class Person implements ID
{
    private int id;
    private String name;

    @XmlElement
    public int getID() { return id; }
    public void setID(int id) { this.id = id; }

    @XmlElement
    public String getName() { return name; }
    public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }
}

@XmlRootElement
public class Record
{
    private Person person;

    @XmlElement
    public Person getPerson() { return person; }
    public void setPerson(Person person) { this.person = person; }
}
```

Both `Person` and `Record` are backed by Hibernate and are proxied by default.  When they get marshalled to XML, Hibernate will fully populate the objects and the output will look like this:

```
<record>
  <person>
    <id>5</id>
    <name>Bob Smith</name>
  </person>
</record>
```

I want to change this so `person` would just have its `id` in the output by default, and therefore Hibernate would not have to populate the object.  I would also like to support fully populating the object when specified by the client.

We had this working with a custom annotation on `getPerson()` in `Record`, and an annotation reader that basically injected an `XmlAdapter` for `ID`-based classes that only returned the result of `getID()`.  When the client specified that a given item should be fully populated, the logic would simply skip injecting of that `XmlAdapter` for that object.  This implementation is ugly, relies on the JAXB and custom annotations being present only on fields, and requires the Sun JAXB implementation.  We're in the process of moving to MOXy and there does not seem to be an equivalent capability.  Note that we're also using Spring 3.2 and are in the process of upgrading to Jersey 2.4, if that helps with anything here.

I've tried using various forms of `XmlAdapter`, `Marshaller.Listener`, and the MOXy ObjectGraph concept, but could not get anything to work in a general manner.  The use of an `XmlAdapter` here is probably the best solution, but we have a *lot* of classes like `Person` and `Record` and there's no way we want to create adapters for each and every one of them.  It doesn't look like `XmlAdapter` plays well with inheritance, so creating one just for `ID` does not work.

Does anyone have any ideas here?  Thanks.

Comment: Check out the slides starting with `Feature: Entity Filtering` from a JavaOne presentation I gave with Michal Gajdoš to see if that is what you are looking for:  https://oracleus.activeevents.com/2013/connect/fileDownload/session/CC099DE9C02B34C23F9AF5236444B3F6/BOF5519_DoughanGajdos.pdf I will ping Michal to see if he will add an answer to your question.

Comment: I looked at Entity Filtering recently, but it didn't seem to work.  I might have been using it incorrectly; I'll try again.  The Jersey pages seem to imply the use of ObjectGraph when using Entity Filtering with MOXy.  I played around with ObjectGraph but that is a total specification: it won't include anything you don't specify, and that's not what I want.  Thanks for the feedback; hopefully you can get Michal to add an answer.